# Generated Rails Models - how will the Migrations run?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

I've generated four models in my Rails App and i now want to create the tables for the same models through the migrations.

The blanks migrations are sitting there in my `/db/migrate` folder, now, in what sequence will the Migrations run if i do `rake db:migrate`

And what should i do to ensure that my tables are generated properly. Should i go ahead and define the associations in my models and then run the migrations?

Because, if i run them as they are, how is Rails gonna figure out the `t.references` part of the Migrations??

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A migration is not directly linked to your model. Before running a migration, you don't need to worry about putting stuff (e.g. associations) in the models or leaving them out. A migration is just a recipe to create or modify a database table and it's fields/columns. You can sort out your model's associations before or after running the migrations. It doesn't matter.

Migrations are run in the order of the filenames of your migrations. If you created your migrations via `script/generate model YourModelName` or `script/generate migration MyMigration` a timestamp (like `20110201165030` for example) is always prepended to the name of the file. That makes sure the migrations are run in the order you generated them.

The `t.references` part doesn't need to figure out anything. It only takes the symbol that comes next, makes it a string, appends `_id` and creates an integer field with that (new) name in your database table. It's just a convention. It certainly does *not* look into your model for any associations.

(The code examples given here are for Rails 2.3. If you're using Rails 3, I think the generate commands are a bit different).

Answer (score 4):

You don't actually need to use references (they don't enforce foreign keys).  References may only makes things easier for you to read if you prefer that syntax.  These two migrations are equivalent:

```
create_table :posts do |t|
  t.references :category
end

create_table :posts do |t|
  t.integer :category_id
end
```

Also, the migrations will be run in the order in which they are defined (i.e the order in which they were created).

Comment: so, for the 4 models, i now have 4 migrations. if i do `rake db:migrate` is that supposed to run all the 4 migrations?

Comment: and one more question, is `id` primary key automatically created as described here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#anatomy-of-a-migration

Comment: Yes. By default id is created. The timestamp columns need to be created using the t.timestamps call if you are using ActiveRecord though.

Comment: Thanks for your answers Pan! I've just started Rails development and wants to learn as much as possible about it.. hence the questions... :)

Comment: `t.references` is usually followed by the _singular_ name of the model it references. So, I think the symbol in your example should be `:category` instead of `:categories`.